# How to use the console within Sublime Text

Tags: plugins, console, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 to code my programs, and  want to run the console within it to compile and run them. Is there any way to embed the console command line inside Sublime Text 2? Is it already there?

I'm using both Windows and Linux.

Comment: Please don't abuse formatting. "[How do I format my posts...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)" is a good read.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think you can try creating a custom **Build System**. Tools --> Build System --> New Build System... This is a simple build script for the C programming language:

```
{
    "cmd" : ["gcc", "$file", "-o", "$file_base_name"],
    "cmd" : ["$file_base_name"],
    "selector" : "source.c",
    "shell" : true,
    "working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

[image]
Change the current build system to the new one in Tools. When you press `CTRL` + `b` it will compile your code and run your executable file. A few syntaxes and options that you can use: http://sublimetext.info/docs/en/reference/build_systems.html There are definitely many more other options that you can declare in the build system. A very useful one is `file_regex`.

Comment: I tried your solution in macOS with Sublime Text 3.2. Only one of the "cmd" gets executed and therefore, throws an error. However, combining the two cmd's with a ```&&```did the trick. Also, the build does not work if the program contains any standard input channels.

Comment: The link is dead. https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html is the new version of it however it relates to Sublime Text 3.

Answer (score 5):

[Terminus](https://github.com/randy3k/Terminus) is a recent plugin, highly under development. It's the best cross-platform console in Sublime Text that I have seen yet.

Answer (score 4):

Will Bond created an excellent plugin for called "[Terminal](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/terminal)" for calling the terminal at project or file levels.

There are also several plugins available that compile at the click of a button:

- "[C# Compile & Run](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/C%23%20Compile%20%26%20Run)"
- "[Type​Script Compiler](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/TypeScript%20Compiler)"
- "[Coffee​Compile](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CoffeeCompile)"

...and so on, depending on your programming language.

I recommend browsing Will's "[Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/)" page if you are not happy with this terminal plugin.